# i'm using oracle live it showing ORA-00936: "missing expression" error

Tags: sql, oracle

i'm using oracle live it showing ORA-00936: "missing expression" error.

```
create table dat(da date); insert into dat values(date('06/03/76', 'dd/mm/yy'));
```

Comment: There's no function `date`, use [date literal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1) instead, which has no format and always represented as `date '1976-03-06'`

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is incorrect. Try this, using `to_date`:

```
create table dat(da date); 
insert into dat values(to_date('06/03/1976', 'dd/mm/yyyy'));
commit;

Table DAT created.


1 row inserted.


Commit complete.
```

Comment: It would be better to use a 4-digit year to avoid ambiguity. The value you have inserted is `2076-03-06`. If the intention was to insert `1976-03-06` then you either want to use a 4-digit year or the `dd/mm/rr` format model. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=33c6746d5d15eb779f994434716ef77c)

Comment: Good point; correction made. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another point of view says that `DATE` is actually OK, but the rest isn't.

If you wanted to use **date literal**, then you'd

```
SQL> create table dat(da date);

Table created.

SQL> insert into dat values(date '1976-03-06');

1 row created.

SQL>
```

because date literal always looks like that: `date` keyword followed by value enclosed into single quotes in `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

Answer (score 0):

“date” is not an Oracle function. Try using to_date